# Finding All TestCases in RALLY regardless of result. (Querying for testcases that have not been run)

Tags: rally, testcase

I am trying to construct a query that will find every created testcase, even if it has not been run (has no result assigned yet).

I started building a custom application based off of the TestCase Pass/Fail history report (source code to starting point is found here http://developer.help.rallydev.com/test-case-passfail-history-app)

However, this application works backwards from how I would expect. It finds a test case result FIRST, and then works backwards to find which test case this result belongs to. Therefore, it does not find test cases that have no verdict assigned (no result).

This is the initial query, directly from Rally's source code:

```
        function runMainQuery(rallyDataSource) {
        document.getElementById("TestCaseInfo").innerHTML = "";
        busySpinner = new rally.sdk.ui.basic.Wait({hideTarget: false});
        busySpinner.display('spinner');
        var daySpan = 30; // how many days back from today for TestCaseResult inclusion
        var dateBoundingClause = '(Date >= "' + previousDate(daySpan) + '")';
        querySpec = {
            key   : "testcaseresults",
            type  : "testcaseresults",
            fetch : 'ObjectID,Build,Date,Verdict,Duration,Tester,UserName,DisplayName,TestCase,FormattedID,Name,WorkProduct',
            query : dateBoundingClause,
            order : 'Date Desc'
        };

        rallyDataSource.findAll(querySpec, showResults);
    }
```

Which searches only for TestCaseRESULTS

I need one that searches for TestCases that do NOT have results (have not been run).

The problem is, I dont know the Rally database structure (table/column names) well enough to know how to construct a query like this.

I tried

`querySpec = {
                key   : "testcase",
                type  : "testcase",
                fetch : 'Name,WorkProduct',
                query : dateBoundingClause,
                order : 'Date Desc'
            };`

But I'm really just shooting in the dark here since I don't know what the database structure looks like.

Any ideas are much appreciated!!!

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The WSAPI documentation located [here](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/) allows you to browse all the available objects and see what fields are available.  Unfortunately the API does not support querying based on an empty collection (Results.count = 0) so you'll have to just pull back all the TestCase objects, include Results in your fetch and check to see if Results.length is 0 on each one.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe I didn't see that document sooner!

Comment: We try to link to it from as many other places in the documentation as possible.  Just out of curiosity how did you get started writing an app?  Did you see all the documentation available on the developer portal at http://developer.rallydev.com?

Comment: Yes I have been exploring the documentation. There certainly is a lot of information. For me it has been difficult because my organization has literally no previous experience writing custom apps for rally, and I have hardly any experience in JavaScript. I'm the only person on this project, so I'm learning everything by myself. However, I'm getting it to work fairly well. It is just taking me a while! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Glad to help.  Thanks for contributing your question to the community.  Please don't hesitate to reach out again.